# convert csv string of numbers into values

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I am trying to read a line of numbers in a csv file, then call on them individually to compute with them. Here is my code so far:

```
import sys
import os
import csv
import numpy as np

with open('data.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    for line in csv_reader:

        x = np.array(line[3])
        print(x)
```

Within this line of the csv file there are numbers with decimals like 4.65 that I need to use in the calculations. I tried things like:

`print(5 + x[14])` but it won't work.

I assume I need to convert the line into a list of integers or something, please help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you really need a numpy array or do regular arrays suffice?

Comment: either one should suffice

Comment: Have you tried [`numpy.loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) or [`numpy.genfromtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html)?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask].  [`float()`'](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float)

Comment: Can you give us an example of a line as it is presented in the `csv` ?

Comment: I'm aware of Float but I couldn't get that to work either for an entire string of numbers coming from the csv file.

Comment: 7.057
7.029
5.843
5.557
4.186
4.1
2.286

Comment: above is a sample of what prints from the line in the csv file. I want to be able to take a specific number and add it to another specific number without  writing out each value, instead I need to get each element by refering to its placment in the line.

Comment: @ChristopherRivas see my edit with `delimiter`

Answer (score 1):

According to your example line you want to add `delimiter=' '` to the `csv.reader()`

```
csv_data = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=' ')
```

---

Taking a guess at the structure of your `csv`, but under the assumption that it contains no headings and you want to keep the decimals:

```
with open('new_data.txt') as csv_file:
    csv_data = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=' ')
        for line in csv_data:
            x = [float(n) for n in line.split(',')]
            print(x)
```

This will fail if you have string values, such as `'A string'`

Comment: it returned: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '5.11,0.5,5.61'

Comment: those are the first numbers in the string

Comment: Can you give me a sample of the csv file?

Comment: ['5.11' '0.5' '5.61']
['5.08' '0.5' '5.58']
['5.06' '0.5' '5.56']
['4.74' '-0.5' '4.24']
['' '' '']
['' '' '']
['6.486' '1' '7.486']
['4.687' '-0.5' '4.187']
['4.488' '-0.5' '3.988']
['4.34' '-0.5' '3.84']

Comment: There are no commas which confuses me, try `line.split(',')` in the list comprehension of my answer.

Comment: sorry, I dont understand where you want me to put it exactly

Comment: and after for n in line

Comment: Please provide us a sample of your **raw** csv file. Just copy and paste a few lines from your csv file in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative to @GiantsLoveDeathMetal's solution with `map` (also it shows a way to provide us a copy/paste-able piece of code containing a sample of your csv file with [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO)) :

**EDITED the `StringIO` to contain data in columns and with empty rows**

```
import csv
import io 

f = io.StringIO("""
7.057
7.029

5.843
5.557
4.186
4.1

2.286""")
csv_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
for line in csv_reader:
    line = list(map(float, filter(None, line)))
    print(line)
```

In python 2 (and in some cases in python 3 if your code works with a generator, which is not the case in this example), you don't need to convert the result of `map` to a list.

So `line = list(map(float, line))` can be replaced by the much cleaner `map(float, line)`. Which *can* be considered cleaner and more explicit than a list comprehension (or a generator expression).

For instance this will work :

```
import csv
import io 

f = io.StringIO("""7.057 7.029 5.843 5.557 4.186 4.1 2.286""")
csv_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
for line in csv_reader:
    line = map(float, line)
    print(sum(line))
# 36.05800000000001
```

If you're interested in the `map` vs list comprehension debate, [here you go for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map).

Comment: Nice `map`. Please get rid of unused `import`s it will make your answer look less like a beast. :)

Comment: thanks Unatiel, however I this solution only works if I keep the string short enough so that its on one line. Also, if I write out the string then there is no point in haveing the csv file, but i need to be calling on the numbers from that file to do computations.

Comment: @ChristopherRivas The `StringIO` is used to provide a file-like object for `csv.reader`. It's a dummy file in memory for demonstration purposes. For your real code, you would of course use `open()` on your file. What we need now is an actual sample of your csv file so we can use the right parameters for `csv.reader`. If the line you've provided in @GiantsLoveDeathMetal's answer is indeed how your csv looks like, then a confirmation would be welcome. Because you've provided a different sample in the comment to your question. Also, a `StringIO` can indeed contain multiple lines.

Comment: my file is an exel file. 5.61
5.58
5.56
4.24


7.486
4.187
3.988
3.84


1.057
1.029
1.843
5.7
9.86
4.1
7.26


7.95
3.071
7.98
8.56


4.36
1.63
1.67
1.875
4.683
1.9
1.4

Comment: sorry, here is what it looks like:                                                                                                                                                          5.61
5.58
5.56
4.24


7.486
4.187
3.988
3.84


1.057
1.029
1.843
5.7
9.86
4.1
7.26


7.95
3.071
7.98
8.56


4.36
1.63
1.67
1.875
4.683
1.9
1.4

Comment: its all these numbers in a column of cells

Comment: Ah, I think I got it. I guess you're copying and pasting directly from excel ? If I'm correct, then you should open your csv with the notepad or whatever text editor, and show us this.

Comment: when i open the exel file in my TextEdit application, it looks like what I most recently commented exept its straight down, and there's a vertial space every 4 or 5 numbers because thats where in the exel file there are empty cells.

Comment: So, no commas or anything other than digits, dots and spaces in the file ?